# Structure of a relational database for comparing multiple dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

We have a Microsoft Access Database at work to track an ongoing list of customers. Each customer has to sign a contract with several departments - totally 13 (!) departments -  for which we want to keep track about the current progress for each customer when a contract is sent and received. This structure looks similar to something like this:

```
    Table 1
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CUSTOMER_ID | ... | DEP_A_SENT | DEP_A_RECEIVED | DEP_B_SENT | DEP_B_RECEIVED | DEP_C_SENT | DEP_C_RECEIVED | ... |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1      | ... | 2015-05-01 |   2015-05-03   | 2015-05-04 |   2015-05-09   | 2015-05-01 |   2015-05-05   | ... |
         2      | ... | 2015-05-01 |   2015-05-05   | 2015-05-01 |   2015-05-03   | 2015-05-13 |       ---      | ... |
         ...
```

- I want to be able to calculate the timespan between `DEP_X_SENT` with `DEP_X_RECEIVED` for customer and department (such as "department A: 2 days, department B: 5 days..." for customer ID 1)
- More importantly, I want to compare all the `DEP_X_RECEIVED` dates with each other for one customer: Determining the first (`MIN`) and the last (`MAX`) date a contract has been received to finding how many days it takes for each customer until all contracts are received. (such as "the contracts were received within 6 days" for customer ID 1, because the first was received on May 3rd. and the last on May 9th). Furthermore, I want to calculate the average timespan this took for all customers. If the contract is not received yet, the is no value in that field.

In MySQL I can work with functions such `GREATEST` and `LEAST` to compare values between different columns, but in Access I have to rely for now on VBA and I think it is considered bad practice. How can I normalize and restructure my table for archieving my goals with rather simple `MAX`, `MIN` and `AVG`operations? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do what you want effectively in MS Access.  Either do the comparisons in VBA or consider switching to another database, such as SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply fold your existing table into this structure:

```
create table TABLE_1 (
    CUSTOMER_ID     int,
    DEPARTMENT_ID   int, -- foreign key reference to DEPARTMENT table
    SENT            date,
    RECEIVED        date
);
```

Now you can perform the required analysis simply, and retrieve the original layout as either a Pivot report or LEFT OUTER JOIN from the DEPARTMENT table to the new TABLE_1.